# Import node package vue.js loader webpack

Tags: node.js, npm, import, webpack, vue.js

I am using the basic **vue** loader setup with webpack(https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/start/setup.html).
In my main.js I import the necessary:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import firebase from 'firebase'
import docx2html from 'docx2html'
```

Both **firebase** and **docx2html** are in the `node_modules` folder under src and specified in the dependencies folder. For some reason firebase is imported, but docx2html can not be found. It returns the error:

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'docx2html' in
>   'C:\path\to\src'.

How should I import docx2html, and why doesn't it work this way?

Comment: make sure it's installed and installed as not dev dependancy or try with require

Comment: I can see the docx2html folder in node_modules

Comment: @samyo it doesn't matter if it's installed as a `devDependency` just as long as it is installed. However a quick look at the issues throws up this: https://github.com/lalalic/docx2html/issues/6 so I guess it's a problem with the package. Somebody in the issues recommends [mammoth](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mammoth) instead